# Spring OAuth2.0 : Spring Authorization Server 1.0 and Resource server in the same boot application

Tags: spring-security

I'm struggling to use the very same Spring Boot 3.0 application as both authentication server and resource server, but until now, I've not been able to make the whole thing working.

First, I defined a very simple RestController:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class PublicAPI {
        
    @GetMapping("/apitest")
    public String test(Principal principal) {
        return " This is a test ==>";
    }
}
```

Then, essentially following the code found in a Sample project of Spring, I managed to setup my boot app as Spring Authorization Server. I'm able to use Postman to get the authentication token using Oauth2 flow: I'm redirected to Spring's standard login page, I log in with credentials, and I get the Token.

Problem is, if I try to `GET` http://localhost:9000/api/apitest` using provided token, I get a 401 response from Spring boot.

This is my Security Configuration:

```
@Bean 
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, CorsConfiguration configCors) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
        http.getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class).oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http
            .exceptionHandling((exceptions) -> exceptions
                .authenticationEntryPoint(
                    new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login"))
            );
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> configCors);
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    @Order(2)
    SecurityFilterChain apiFilter(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .securityMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()
                    .and()
            .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt();
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean 
    @Order(3)
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http, CorsConfiguration configCors) throws Exception {
        http
            .securityMatcher("/oauth2/**", "/login")
            .authorizeHttpRequests()
                .requestMatchers("/login", "/oauth2/**")
                .authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults());
        http.cors().configurationSource(request -> configCors);
        return http.build();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public CorsConfiguration corsConfiguration() throws Exception {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(List.of("*"));
        return configuration;
    }
```

If I try to access another Spring API in a different Spring Boot application which uses the first one as Authentication Server I get no errors.
Pretty sure that there's something wrong my configuration... any hint will be greatly appreciated !

Comment: Add `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE` to your `application.properties` and check the console log. I think that you are seeing the 401 from the `/error` page but maybe there is another error that you are not seeing, so checking the logs could help.

Comment: I don't see any securityMatcher in security filter-chain bean with order 1 => it always matches and others are not evaluated. Have you tried to configure it with order 4 instead, so that others match for the routes it are configured for and this bean with no securityMatcher is used as default when routes are not matched with other filter-chains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the very end, it turned out that another filter has been configured:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class LoopbackIpRedirectFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getServerName().equals("localhost") && request.getHeader("host") != null) {
            UriComponents uri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpRequest(new ServletServerHttpRequest(request))
                    .host("127.0.0.1").build();
            response.sendRedirect(uri.toUriString());
            return;
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

Removing the *LoopbackIpRedirectFilter* problem was fixed